# Quick way to estimate difference between colours

Tags: java

I am implementing an image processing task in which I am comparing colours of pixels a *huge* number of times and I need the comparison code to execute as fast as possible. Currently the image is in ARGB_8888 format: I am ignoring transparency. So I am using the sum of absolute differences in red, green and blue as my measure of the difference in colour, though this choice of difference measure is not set in stone (e.g. maybe the sum of the squares of the differences may be better in some sense).

```
int coldif(int c1,int c2)
{
    return (Math.abs(( c1&0xff)          -( c2&0xff)))             +
           (Math.abs(((c1&0xff00)>> 8)   -((c2&0xff00)>> 8)) )     +
           (Math.abs(((c1&0xff0000)>> 16)-((c2&0xff0000)>> 16)));
}
```

So I am interested in ways of making my existing algorithm faster, or alternatively using a different measure of colour difference, or even converting the entire image into a different colour representation as a pre-process which would then allow a different colour difference algorithm to be used.

Comment: What kind of "difference" do you need? For example, the obvious solution of "return c1 == c2" provides only same/not same difference. Do you need to know "how much different" colors are or to compare the difference of lets say (c1,c2) with the difference of (c1,c3)?

Comment: @Oleg Estekhin: I need some kind of degree of difference measure. So just using == or != is not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this really a bottleneck? What I can think of is reducing the amount of shift operations like this:

```
int coldif(int c1,int c2)
{
    return (Math.abs((c1&0x0000ff) - (c2&0x0000ff))      ) +
           (Math.abs((c1&0x00ff00) - (c2&0x00ff00)) >>  8) +
           (Math.abs((c1&0xff0000) - (c2&0xff0000)) >> 16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant that is a bit faster but still can be useful to compare differences between multiple color pairs:

```
int coldif( int c1, int c2 ) {
    int d = c1 ^ c2;
    return ( d & 0xff ) + ( ( d >>> 8 ) & 0xff ) + ( ( d >>> 16 ) & 0xff );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to produce the same values as the OP (just tried it in my program)... is that a mistake, or are you saying that this is simply a different type of measure.

Comment: It is different type of measure.